# How to get all the values in a column sequentially using SqlAlchemy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have a Profile named `School`

Table is :

```
   id[pk]     name    division
   ------     ----    --------
 1  100       John      2
 2  102       Maria     5
 3  108       Hooper    4
```

PK Column Type: 'Numeric'.

How do get all the id values sequentially from the very first to the last using python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
for row in dbsession.query(School.id).order_by(School.id):
    print(row[0])
```

Comment: Got an error: "TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str." .  The column is a Numeric type.

Comment: Edited the answer - try again please

Comment: I did and worked.. fine, Thanks! sry for not mentioning Column Type in the post. now edited!

Comment: No problem. Remember to hit the correct answer checkmark below voting if you managed to solve the issue.